# How to reduce one day in existing date column in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update

I have table `tbl_dtcount`. In that table there is one column for date.
Now I need to reduce one day for each and every rows in that date field. The date is beginning from `2012-05-19` to `2012-07-03`. What is the MySQL update statement to perform this?

Answer (score 5):

How about this.

```
Update tbl_dtcount
set mydate = DATE_SUB(mydate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
where <conditions>;
```

Comment: It is not possible because, there is 43600 rows to update. if we use where conditions it needs63 times to update stmt

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_column = DATE_SUB('1998-01-02', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
....
```

see detail [MySQL DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)